# how to cite an unpublished thesis?

Tags: bibtex, thesis

How to cite an unpublished thesis (I have not passed my PhD exam yet; so my thesis has not been published yet)?

In BibTex, I tried:

```
@phdthesis{r2014,
    author = {... ...},
    title = {...},
    school = {...},
    year = {2014}
        %note = {unpublished thesis}
}
```

however, the last entry is just a "note" and "unpublished" does not show up in the citation output.

On the other hand, if I use `@unpublished` rather than `@phdthesis`, the output does not show anything about this work being a phd thesis. 
any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean 'unpublished thesis'?

Comment: I have not passed my PhD exam yet; so my thesis has not been published yet. (I edited the question as well.)

Comment: My guess is that the note doesn't show up because you have commented it out with ``%``?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? If you use the `@misc` entry type, you could put the "unpublished thesis" bit -- or should that maybe be "to be published thesis" or "Ph.D. thesis, fortcoming" -- in the `note` field.

Comment: I often just include this information in the `year` field.  `year="2014, to be published"`, or similar.

Comment: The correct format in Chicago style is as follows for a bibliography: Lastname, First. "Title." PhD dissertation, University of X. 2014.

Answer (score 6):

I would say this depends on your bibliographic style and personal taste.

Using `biblatex` and the default style, you can get (code below):
[image: Compilation with 4 differents entries]

> On the other hand, if I use @unpublished rather than @phdthesis, the
>   output does not show anything about this work being a phd thesis. any
>   ideas?

There is something else : the school is not printed, so you have to tweak to add it (as a note, or something else).

Personally, I would definitely choose the `@phdthesis` for

- This is what this document is,
- It will be easier to update your `bib` file, as you will just have to comment the `unpublished`.
- It reflects the fact that this document is "scholar".

---

---

**Code :**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@phdthesis{mephd2014,
author={Myself, Roberto},
title={A great memoir},
school={UCXDX},
year={2014},
note={unpublished thesis}
}
@phdthesis{mepdh2014bis,
author={Myself, Roberto},
title={A great memoir},
school={UCXDX},
year={2014},
addendum={unpublished thesis}
}
@unpublished{meunpub2014,
author={Myself, Roberto},
title={A great memoir},
school={UCXDX},
year={2014},
note={unpublished thesis}
}
@unpublished{meunpub2014bis,
author={Myself, Roberto},
title={A great memoir},
school={UCXDX},
year={2014},
addendum={unpublished thesis}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|@phdthesis| with note: \cite{mephd2014}\\
\verb|@phdthesis| with addendum: \cite{mepdh2014bis}\\
\verb|@unpublished| with note: \cite{meunpub2014}\\
\verb|@unpublished| with addendum: \cite{meunpub2014bis}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```