# How to cite an unpublished preprint with Bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I am learning Bibtex and am doing well with those references which I can find with google scholar. But I need to cite an unpublished preprint *Combinatorial Group Theory In Homotopy Theory I* by Fred R Cohen, available at [his web page](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/cohf/).

Is there a standard format for situations like this? I need to cite another preprint which is not even available on web site; I contacted the authors personally to get a copy. How should I cite it using Bibtex in this case?

Hopefully this question is not a duplicate. I tried to search this site and found [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180696/how-to-cite-an-unpublished-thesis), but the question is not exactly the same as what I want to ask and there is no answer for the question so far.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: @Mico, \bibliographystyle{plain}. Actually I am quite new to bibtex and have no idea which one I should use.

Comment: Since you're using the `plain` bibliography style, you could use either the type `@unpublished` or the catch-all type `@misc`. For either type, use the `note` field to provide URL and similar information. Which bibliography style you should (or must) use depends importantly on the style guidelines of the journal or outfit you wish to submit your paper to.

Comment: @Mico, I am not familiar with it; could you please give me an example?

Comment: Any introduction to BibTeX explains nicely which entry types recognize which fields.

Comment: Thanks @Mico! Not sure if it is proper to ask another question here: Can I always trust the entry generated by google scohlar? Occasionally I found typos there.

Comment: As a general rule, you should always check the correctness of *all* entries you've obtained online for correctness. In my experience, even entry information derived from the publishers' own websites isn't 100% reliable.

Comment: Thanks @Mico! I found this description: Unpublished: A document having an author and title, but not formally published.
Required fields: author, title, note. Optional fields: month,
year. What is the required field "note"?

Comment: It says that a note is "Any additional information that can help the reader." Then why it is required instead of optional?

Comment: For entries of type `@unpublished`, the `note` field generally contains information about the author's affiliation, a web address, or whatever else is deemed important and helpful to the reader -- and doesn't belong in one of the other fields.

Comment: @Mico, then in my case, if I write "note={preprint on webpage at http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/cohf/}", is it considered enough and suitable?

Comment: I suppose that if you've loaded the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages, you could also encase the URL string in a `\url{...}` directive. If nothing else, doing so will help LaTeX find a decent line break in the long string, should It be necessary to do so.

Comment: Thanks again!! My last question: For the other preprint which is not available online, can I simply wrtie "note={preprint}"?

Comment: I'd say so. Readers might appreciate information about the author's affiliation, if known. I'm afraid I've got to sign off for now as I've boarded a transatlatantic flight and need to turn off my smartphone. Back online in about eight hours...

Comment: @Zuriel: if you're learning `bibtex, you should consider using the `biblatex` package, that' is both powerful  and easy to customise. It works with bibtex, but is designed for `biber`. Not sure it's relevant to your case, but it also has an `online` entry type.

Comment: Generally, a preprint should be formatted using `@techreport`. Most journals nowadays mark `@techreport` as unpublished.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov - I beg to differ. The `@techreport` entry type should be used primarily for items issued as part of a working paper, discussion paper, or similarly numbered series of papers. That's why the `@techreport` entry type has fields such as `institution` (required) and `type` and `number` (optional).

Comment: If you are new to bibtex, then you should definitely use biblatex. Those questions might be of use : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex Have a look at the package book, also.

Comment: @Mico Would you like to provide an answer to this question?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

(This is a compilation of some of the comments I provided when the query was first posted.)

Since you're using the `plain` bibliography style, you could use either the `@unpublished` entry type or the catch-all `@misc` entry type for the paper at hand. With either of these two entry types, I suggest you use the `note` field to provide URL and similar information. Incidentally, based on the description you've provided, I would *not* use the entry type `@techreport` for this paper. The `@techreport` entry type should be used primarily for items issued as part of a working paper series, discussion paper series, or similarly numbered series of papers. That's why the `@techreport` entry type has fields such as `institution` (required) and `type` and `number` (optional).

Aside: which bibliography style you should -- or must -- use depends importantly on the style guidelines of the journal or outfit you intend to submit your paper to. One of the main advantages of using BibTeX (or, say, `biblatex`) for generating bibliographies and citation call-outs is that it's straightforward to switch between (pre-defined) bibliography styles.

Regarding your first follow-up question,

> Can I always trust the entry generated by google scohlar? Occasionally I found typos there.

As a general rule, you should *always double-check* the correctness of all entries you've obtained online. In my experience, even bibliographic information derived from the publishers' own websites isn't 100 percent reliable.

You also asked,

> I found this description: `@Unpublished`: A document having an author and title, but not formally published. Required fields: `author`, `title`, `note`. Optional fields: `month`, `year`. What is the required field "note"? ... It says that a note is "Any additional information that can help the reader." Then why it is required instead of optional? ... if I write "`note={preprint on webpage at math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/cohf}`", is it considered enough and suitable?

For entries of type `@unpublished`, the `note` field generally contains information about the author's institutional affiliation (if known), a web address, and any other pieces of information which may be important and helpful to the reader and which do not belong in any of the other fields.

If you've loaded the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages, you could (should, actually...) encase any URL strings inside `note` fields in a `\url{...}` directive. E.g., you might write

```
note={preprint on webpage at \url{math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/cohf}},
```

This will help LaTeX find a decent line break in the URL string, should It be necessary to do so.

Comment: Just today a friend mentioned that annoyingly a publisher's own bibtex entry (provided on their website) was faulty. So yes, I just want to second the "always double check" part.